# ¿Como puedo guardar los datos de un arhivo en diccionario en python?

Tags: python, archivo, diccionarios, lua

Como puedo guardar los datos de un archivo que tiene un diccionario anidado adentro, en un diccionario en python. La estructura del archivo la adjunto en la imagen:
[image: ejemplo]

Comment: Si el formato del archivo de uso común, podrían existir parsers que hagan todo el trabajo duro. Si no, tendrás que escribir un programa que lea el archivo, lo interprete y vaya generando el diccionario.

Comment: Viendo que, por la etiqueta y sintaxis, es probable que sea lua, deberás conseguir un parser que cree un arbol de sintaxis abstracta a partir de un código lua. Y procesar ese arbol para ir extrayendo y transformando cada nodo en el correspondiente objeto de Python